# turnpage inverts table in aastex 6.3

Tags: tables, rotating, aastex

I'm using aastex 6.3 to format a document and I have need to include several tables in landscape mode.  I have tried the rotatetable environment that comes with aastex, but while this would work if I had a single table, I can't make this work to show multiple tables side-by-side.  I've therefore turned to the turnpage environment that comes with revtex, which aastex is based on.  However, while it correctly rotates the table header and caption 90 degrees, it rotates the actual table a further 90 degress, rendering it vertical and upside-down!

This appears to be an issue in the cls file itself, because it works properly when I use the aastex6 document class that I had on my computer (but interestingly, the aastex6.cls I downloaded from the AAS website still has this issue), but it doesn't work with aastex63.  Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,preprint]{aastex63}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{turnpage}
\begin{table}
\caption{Test}
\begin{deluxetable}{lcccc}[H]
\tablehead{
\colhead{ID} & \colhead{Mag.} & \colhead{Period} & \colhead{(Distance)} & \colhead{Lum.}}
\startdata
\textbf{2449084}  & 15.018 & 0.740 &  3172 & 8.46\\
2577756 & 15.514 & 0.870 &  2262 & 2.73\\
\enddata
\end{deluxetable}
\end{table}
\end{turnpage}

\end{document}
```

I also have a screenshot of what it looks like when compiled:

[image: Bad Compile]

and what I want it to look like (compiled with aastex6):

[image: Good Compile]

Could someone help me get this to work properly?

Comment: Hi I work for the AAS Journals. Are you asking for help with just this example, or do you want help with the original problem: "show multiple tables side-by-side [in landscape mode]"?

Comment: Either one would help; I'm not particularly attached to this method of showing the tables, it was just the one that came closest to what I want to do (and if this is a bug it should be looked at regardless).  If there's another way to do it, however, that is fine too.

Comment: Okay, I'm still not clear on the original desired layout (multiple landscape tables side by side), but if you remove the \begin and \end{table} and put the caption inside \begin{deluxetable} then I think you get what you want.  In any case one should not wrap deluxetable in table.

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion, and it comes from me not explaining clearly.  I want multiple tables, as in columns of data, but they're all part of a single table (they're all part of table 3 in my document) that has a single caption.  That's why the outer table is there; it acts as the container for the subtables that are referenced elsewhere and holds the caption that correctly spans the entire width of the (multiple) deluxe tables.  I believe your solution would result in multiple numbered tables, each with a separate caption.

Comment: I have found a solution that gives me precisely what I desire:  using the sidewaystable environment from the rotating package allows for side-by-side tables in landscape.